# Recursively remove object from nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

i've got array like this. Unlimited number of nesting possible

```
const myArray = [
  {
   id: 1, 
   children: [
              { 
                id: 3,
                children: []
              }
             ]
  },
  {
   id: 2, children: []
  }
]
```

Please, help me to remove any object by id and return new array without it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `recursiveRemove`  function will recursively remove the elements from the array and return the new list.

The map function creates copy of the items in the array, you can remove the map if you do not need to retain the original array's sanity.

```
function recursiveRemove ( list, id ) {
    return list.map ( item => { return {...item} }).filter ( item => {
        if ( 'children' in item ) {
            item.children = recursiveRemove ( item.children, id );
        }
        return item.id !== id;
    });
}
const test1 = recursiveRemove ( myArray, 1);
const test2 = recursiveRemove ( myArray, 2);
const test3 = recursiveRemove ( myArray, 3);
```

Answer (score 7):

Using array methods and recursive function:

```js
function fn(arr, id) {
  return arr
    .filter((el) => el.id !== id)
    .map((el) => {
      if (!el.children || !Array.isArray(el.children)) return el;
      el.children = fn(el.children, id);
      return el;
    });
}

const myArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    children: [
      {
        id: 3,
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    children: [],
  },
];

console.log(fn(myArray,1))
console.log(fn(myArray,2))
console.log(fn(myArray,3))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function removeFromArrayOfObj (array, idToRemove) {
  for (const [i, e] of array.entries()) {
    if (e.id === idToRemove) {
     array.splice(i, 1)
     continue
    }
   if (e.children) {
     removeFromArrayOfObj(e.children, idToRemove)
    }
 }
 return array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could destructure the object and take `id` and `children` out of the object. Then get a new object with the rest of the former object and map the children.

```js
const
    withoutId = ({ id, children, ...o }) => ({ ...o, children: children.map(withoutId) }),
    array = [{ id: 1, children: [{ id: 3, children: [] }] }, { id: 2, children: [] }],
    without = array.map(withoutId);

console.log(without);
```

Comment: The op asked: `Please, help me to remove any object by id...`

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to me to separate out the recursive traversal and filtering from the actual details of removing a certain id.  So I would write a more generic `filterDeep` function which keeps only those objects where a predicate is true, recursing into `children` nodes.

Then we can supply a predicate to it that checks whether an item matches a specific id.  Or rather, since we're removing those that match, our predicate actually checks whether our node *doesn't match* the id.

This is an implementation of that idea:

```js
const filterDeep = (pred) => (xs) =>
  xs .flatMap (x => pred (x)
    ? [{... x, children: filterDeep (pred) (x .children || [])}] 
    : []
  )
  
const removeId = (id) =>  
  filterDeep (x => x.id !== id)

const myArray = [{id: 1, children: [{id: 3, children: []}]}, {id: 2, children: []}]

console .log (removeId (1) (myArray))
console .log (removeId (2) (myArray))
console .log (removeId (3) (myArray))
console .log (removeId (42) (myArray))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This will include a `children` node even if the original didn't have one.  If we wanted to include it only if there was one to begin with we could change it to something like this:

```js
const filterDeep = (pred) => (xs) =>
  xs .flatMap (x => pred (x) 
    ? [{
        ... x, 
        ... (x.children ? {children: filterDeep (pred) (x .children || [])} : {})
      }] 
    : []
  )
```

Or with a little more sophistication, we could choose to include a `children` node only when it's available in the parent and the results are non-empty.  That's left as an exercise for the reader.  :-)

Comment: perfect timing for this question to come along! and perfect answer to pair with it!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, homework problems.

- write 'kill_entries_with_id(child_array, id_to_kill)'.  For each element of the child array, it should `del` the element if its id matches.  Otherwise, it should recursively call itself with the element's children.
- Note that you should walk the array backwards by index so you don't have to worry about deleting elements mucking up your loop.  Consider `list(range(10,-1,-1)`