# Remove a item in a nested JSON array using Id/Key

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I have the following json setup which imitates a folder structure:

```
    {
    "boxId": "45345344535",
    "modifiedDate": "2023-08-18T11:07:43-04:00",
    "name": "FolderTest",
    "size": 7751630,
    "files": [
        {
            "boxId": "2343214243",
            "modifiedDate": null,
            "name": "Original Preprint Submission.pdf",
            "size": null
        },
        {
            "boxId": "43534534543534",
            "modifiedDate": null,
            "name": "Original Supporting docs.msg",
            "size": null
        }
    ],
    "folders": [
        {
            "boxId": "34534534534535",
            "modifiedDate": "2023-08-18T11:07:02-04:00",
            "name": "Round 1",
            "size": 4092614,
            "files": [
                {
                    "boxId": "45325252435235",
                    "modifiedDate": null,
                    "name": "Round 1 Preprint.pdf",
                    "size": null
                },
                {
                    "boxId": "45436567546754",
                    "modifiedDate": null,
                    "name": "Round 1 response.pdf",
                    "size": null
                },
                {
                    "boxId": "324243245435345",
                    "modifiedDate": null,
                    "name": "Round 1 supporting doc 1.pdf",
                    "size": null
                },
                {
                    "boxId": "3421342142142134",
                    "modifiedDate": null,
                    "name": "Round 1 supporting doc 2.docx",
                    "size": null
                }
            ],
            "folders": []
        }
    ]
}
```

So I am trying to create a recursive function that takes the id and also the original array then finds the match then removes that file node. I found a similar post here:

[Recursively remove object from nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61656132/recursively-remove-object-from-nested-array)

But I am struggling to adapt it to my json structure .

Comment: "I am struggling to adapt it to my json structure" -> can you please share in the question your current code and how it fails? (result if different from expected / error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **IN-PLACE**:

```js
const removeNode = (parent, id) => {
  let idx = parent.files.findIndex(({boxId}) => id === boxId);
  if(idx >= 0){
    parent.files.splice(idx, 1);
    return true;
  }
  for(let i = 0; i < parent.folders.length; i++){
    if(parent.folders[i].boxId === id){
      parent.folders.splice(i, 1);
      return true;
    }
    if(removeNode(parent.folders[i], id)){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

console.log('removing 3421342142142134:', removeNode(root, '3421342142142134'));
console.log(root);
```

```html
<script>
const root = {
 
    "boxId": "45345344535",
    "modifiedDate": "2023-08-18T11:07:43-04:00",
    "name": "FolderTest",
    "size": 7751630,
    "files": [
        {
            "boxId": "2343214243",
            "modifiedDate": null,
            "name": "Original Preprint Submission.pdf",
            "size": null
        },
        {
            "boxId": "43534534543534",
            "modifiedDate": null,
            "name": "Original Supporting docs.msg",
            "size": null
        }
    ],
    "folders": [
        {
            "boxId": "34534534534535",
            "modifiedDate": "2023-08-18T11:07:02-04:00",
            "name": "Round 1",
            "size": 4092614,
            "files": [
                {
                    "boxId": "45325252435235",
                    "modifiedDate": null,
                    "name": "Round 1 Preprint.pdf",
                    "size": null
                },
                {
                    "boxId": "45436567546754",
                    "modifiedDate": null,
                    "name": "Round 1 response.pdf",
                    "size": null
                },
                {
                    "boxId": "324243245435345",
                    "modifiedDate": null,
                    "name": "Round 1 supporting doc 1.pdf",
                    "size": null
                },
                {
                    "boxId": "3421342142142134",
                    "modifiedDate": null,
                    "name": "Round 1 supporting doc 2.docx",
                    "size": null
                }
            ],
            "folders": []
        }
    ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: doesn't work if trying to remove a root node

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started -

```js
function removeId({ files = [], folders = [], ...node }, id){
  return node.boxId === id
    ? []
    : [{ ...node, files: files.flatMap(f => removeId(f, id)), folders: folders.flatMap(f => removeId(f, id)) }]
}
```

Run the demo to verify in your own browser -

```js
function removeId({ files = [], folders = [], ...node }, id){
  return node.boxId === id
    ? []
    : [{ ...node, files: files.flatMap(f => removeId(f, id)), folders: folders.flatMap(f => removeId(f, id)) }]
}

const node = {boxId: "45345344535",modifiedDate: "2023-08-18T11:07:43-04:00",name: "FolderTest",size: 7751630,files: [{boxId: "2343214243",modifiedDate: null,name: "Original Preprint Submission.pdf",size: null},{boxId: "43534534543534",modifiedDate: null,name: "Original Supporting docs.msg",size: null}],folders: [{boxId: "34534534534535",modifiedDate: "2023-08-18T11:07:02-04:00",name: "Round 1",size: 4092614,files: [{boxId: "45325252435235",modifiedDate: null,name: "Round 1 Preprint.pdf",size: null},{boxId: "45436567546754",modifiedDate: null,name: "Round 1 response.pdf",size: null},{boxId: "324243245435345",modifiedDate: null,name: "Round 1 supporting doc 1.pdf",size: null},{boxId: "3421342142142134",modifiedDate: null,name: "Round 1 supporting doc 2.docx",size: null}],folders: []}]}

console.log(removeId(node, "34534534534535"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```js
[
  {
    "boxId": "45345344535",
    "modifiedDate": "2023-08-18T11:07:43-04:00",
    "name": "FolderTest",
    "size": 7751630,
    "files": [
      {
        "boxId": "2343214243",
        "modifiedDate": null,
        "name": "Original Preprint Submission.pdf",
        "size": null,
        "files": [],
        "folders": []
      },
      {
        "boxId": "43534534543534",
        "modifiedDate": null,
        "name": "Original Supporting docs.msg",
        "size": null,
        "files": [],
        "folders": []
      }
    ],
    "folders": []
  }
]
```

Comment: seems quite slow to use `flatMap()` and copy the whole structure. maybe this is what the OP wants

Comment: `removeId` is written here as a pure function, it does not mutate the input. what might "seem quite slow" is not actually slow, objects are copied by reference.

Answer (score -1):

You want to create a recursive function that searches for an item with a given `boxId` and removes it from the given JSON structure. Here's how you can do it:

- Check the root level of the JSON for any files or folders with the given `boxId`.
- If a match is found at the root level, remove it and return.
- If no match is found, then recursively check inside each folder's files and subfolders.
- If a match is found inside a folder, remove it and return.

Here's the code:

```
def remove_node_by_id(data, boxId):
    # Check and remove from files at current level
    data['files'] = [file for file in data.get('files', []) if file['boxId'] != boxId]
    
    # Check folders
    for i, folder in enumerate(data.get('folders', [])):
        # If folder matches the boxId, remove it
        if folder['boxId'] == boxId:
            del data['folders'][i]
            return
        # Else, check recursively inside the folder
        remove_node_by_id(folder, boxId)
    
    # Clean up any empty folders after the removal
    data['folders'] = [folder for folder in data.get('folders', []) if folder['files'] or folder['folders']]
```

To use the function:

```
json_data = {
    # ... [your JSON structure here]
}

boxId_to_remove = "45325252435235"
remove_node_by_id(json_data, boxId_to_remove)
```

This function will modify the given `json_data` in-place to remove the item with the specified `boxId`.

Comment: I am using javascript. What language is this?

Comment: that is python, i'll try a javascript answer for you